# bidirectional google wave jabber gateway for google talk or ichat

Tags: xmpp, google-wave, ichat

I've understood that Google Wave is built around the XMPP platform, as such I was thinking that it should be possible to access it with a jabber client like ichat or google talk. The advantage is that it's a lot faster to answer or read specific waves then going through a javascript jit in a browser.
Now you can add the xmpplite bot http://wave-xmpp.appspot.com/public/xmpplite.htm
but that is gwave -> xmpp only. It would be nice if one could also post to the wave with a jabber or e-mail client. Does anyone know a bot or a method of doing so?

Answer (score 0):

The wave federation protocol is based on XMPP, but XMPP/BOSH isn't used for client-server communication, so it's not possible directly yet. However, since Google App Engine's XMPP service is bidirectional, there really isn't anything stopping the development of a robot which can be gwave <-> xmpp.